# Finding curve that minimizes an integral due to constraints

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, curvature

In the euclidean plane I want a smooth curve $\gamma (t)$ which satisfy:$$\gamma (0)=(0,0)\quad\quad \gamma '(0)=(1,0)\quad\quad n\in \mathbb{N}\land n\neq 1\Rightarrow \gamma ^{(n)}(0)=(0,0)\\\gamma (s)=(1,1)\quad\quad \gamma '(s)=(0,1)\quad\quad n\in \mathbb{N}\land n\neq 1\Rightarrow \gamma ^{(n)}(s)=(0,0)$$

Where $s>0$ is the arclength of $\gamma$. There are many such, but I think uniqueness is obtained by contraining to those that minimize $\int \kappa (s)^2ds$, and satisfy:$$0\leq t\leq s\Rightarrow \|\gamma '(t)\|=1$$

How can this curve be found/approximated? Does $\gamma$ solve some well-known differential equation that I can look up/solve?

Comment: I think you can find the following paper useful people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/AIM/AIM-612-OCR.pdf

Comment: The boundary conditions on $\gamma^{(n)}$, $n>1$, should be disregarded. They do not change anything in the geometry of minimizing curve, because they can be achieved by adding tiny straight segments to both ends of curves, with no appreciable impact on the integral norm of curvature. Their only effect is the absense of true minimizing curve; you'll only have a minimizing sequence within the family of admissible curves, whose limit lies outside of the family.